# Python/Myro: Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs

Tags: python, exception, attributeerror, python-2.4, myro

My beginners-level Python course uses Python 2.4 and Myro, the latter of which has caused me nothing but trouble. At this point in the class I can't even run the code I've written nine times out of ten, even though sometimes it will end up working despite me changing nothing. Even the example programs the class provides end up giving me errors. I'm assuming that the problem is with the Myro framework itself, and is not my own error. The teacher is unresponsive, so I've turned to this site. Here's the error I've been getting.

```
Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Python24\lib\atexit.py", line 24, in _run_exitfuncs
        func(*targs, **kargs)
    File "C:\Python24\lib\site-packages\myro\__init__.py", line 784, in _cleanup
        if "robot" in myro.globvars.robot.robotinfo:
AttributeError: 'SimScribbler' object has no attribute 'robotinfo'
Error in sys.exitfunc:
Myro is stopping: -------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Python24\lib\atexit.py", line 24, in _run_exitfuncs
        func(*targs, **kargs)
    File "C:\Python24\lib\site-packages\myro\__init__.py", line 784, in _cleanup
        if "robot" in myro.globvars.robot.robotinfo:
AttributeError: 'SimScribbler' object has no attribute 'robotinfo'
Exception exceptions.AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute '__del__'" in <bound method SynthAndOutput.__del__ of <pyTTS.sapi.SynthAndOutput object at 0x02392430>> ignored
```

As I said, the problem seems to be with Myro itself and not my own code. I've tried re-installing both Python and Myro according to the class' written instructions, and I have even tried using a different computer, to no avail. This problem is way over my head, what can I do to solve it?